# Python & Pandas: Value lookup and extraction between columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup, extract

EDIT: I'm just looking for **hint** on how to approach this issue.

I'm trying to perform a fairly advanced lookup of values in Pandas DF, but I have no clue how to approach it.

**The logic should be as follows:**

1. Find if there is matching value of id1 in id2.
2. If there is a match, list all content values matching id1 and to each individual value assign all values matching id2
3. Do this for the whole dataframe and sum all occurrences / variations

**My DF looks like this:**

```
id1 id2 content
20  10  item 1
20  10  item 2
20  10  item 3
30  20  item 4
30  20  item 5
30  20  item 6
```

**And I need to get the following:**

```
content  previous_content   sum_of_occurances
item 4   item 1             1
item 4   item 2             1
item 4   item 3             1
item 5   item 1             1
item 5   item 2             1
item 5   item 3             1
item 6   item 1             1
item 6   item 2             1
item 6   item 3             1
```

Count anyone give me a hint how should I approach it in Python? I'm fairly new, so it may be a beginner-level issue. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post the code you've written so far, and where it's going wrong.  It'd also be helpful if you can flesh out your edge cases a bit.  For example, what to do with data in `df` if there is no match between `id1` and `id2`?  What's an example of a case where `sum_of_occurrences` is greater than 1?  What are "individuals" represented by in your data?  And what do you mean by "sum all...variations", what is the difference between a variation and an occurrence?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I actually didn't get very far since I got stuck right at the beginning after creating an array of unique items appearing in content which I wanted to use to detect matching id1 and id2s, but being new, that's how far I've gotten. To answer your questions: if there isn't a match between id1 and id2, move to the next id1. sum_of_occurances means would be greater than 1 if a combination of items occurred multiple times. Individual value = any item corresponding to id1. Variation and occurance are the same things. Do you have any ideas how can I tackle it? :-)

Comment: You're likely to get better help, faster, with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or at least as close to one as you can get).  Include code to build your initial data frame, along with example input and desired output that covers all the conditions you care about.  People on SO tend to be a little sensitive about questions that come across as "do this for me", rather than "I've gotten this far, here's what I've done, can you show me what went wrong?"  It's a fine line, granted - but the more you can aim towards an MCVE, the better.

Comment: Thank you, I don't want anyone to do it for me, just point me towards the right direction in how to approach it, but yes, I think I know what you mean.

Comment: Hey Luna - like Andrew, I'm having a little trouble figuring out exactly what kind of output you want.  Does your second dataframe really represent the outcome you expect from processing the first dataframe?  Because the first dataframe doesn't have any rows where `id1` and `id2` match, but the sum column does have values in the second dataframe.

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""id1  id2  content
20  10  item 1
20  10  item 2
20  10  item 3
30  20  item 4
30  20  item 5
30  20  item 6"""), sep='  ', engine='python')
```

Use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to (self) join dataframe on id1/id2 and add suffix to common columns:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df, df, how='inner', left_on='id2', 
                     right_on='id1', suffixes=('','_previous'))
# Take essential columns
merged_df = merged_df[['content','content_previous']]
```

Groupby content columns, take the count to get number of occurances, rename the "index" column:

```
# Reset index so we have something to count, then group by
grouped_df = merged_df.reset_index().groupby(['content','content_previous']).count()
# Reset index and change name of column
final_df = grouped_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'sum_of_occurances'})  #There may be a better to get unique count across two columns
```

Output:

```
  content content_previous  sum_of_occurances
0  item 4           item 1                  1
1  item 4           item 2                  1
2  item 4           item 3                  1
3  item 5           item 1                  1
4  item 5           item 2                  1
5  item 5           item 3                  1
6  item 6           item 1                  1
7  item 6           item 2                  1
8  item 6           item 3                  1
```